# How to prevent a listener method from being called during addEventListener in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am adding a listener method like below -

```
import { AppState } from 'react-native';
AppState.addEventListener('change', this.checkStatus);
```

But here the method `checkStatus` is being called one time initially, which I think, is while executing the above line. Is it the expected behavior or am I doing it the wrong way ? I have a scenario where I do not want this function to be invoked unless there is a change in AppState. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: if your this.checkStatus is called is due to an change event was fired, may be you are adding listener in a worng place

Comment: @F.bernal Adding the listener in constructor. Should it be moved to somewhere else ?

Comment: The best way is add it in componentDidMount and then remove the listener in componentWillUnmount

Comment: Still the method is invoked when I do ```AppState.addEventListener('change', this.checkStatus);```

Comment: As I said, you are getting called due to a state change was produced in the application. If you check the App state received it should be 'active' that means the application is in the foreground. I don't know where the problem is with this. Show more code to be able to see what is going on

Comment: Actually, when I am adding listener from ```componentDidMount```, app is already in active state, right ? So I am confused why the listener is called because app was in active state and there was no change in state.